# Am I placing high and low pressure zones correctly?

Tags: climate, earth-like

I'm using Geoff's Climate Cookbook to try and make the climate of my world, but I'm really struggling and I don't understand much. I've put the high and low pressure zones down on my map, but I feel like I might be doing it wrong. My world is identical to Earth, just with different continents.

This is for January
[image]

and this is for July
[image]

Orange is high pressure, blue is low pressure, and the lines in the landmasses are supposed to be mountains.

Am I doing it right? If not, how do I fix it? And any advice for what I have to do after this would be really appreciated.

Comment: I can’t personally answer this and have yet to reach this point of my project, but I do have some resources. Madeline James has a great blog on making a realistic world and did(imo) a decent amount of research. https://www.madelinejameswrites.com/blog/air-currents-and-pressure Worldbuilding Pasta did the same. It is a bit harder to find but it is in the Winds and Perception sections. https://worldbuildingpasta.blogspot.com/2020/05/an-apple-pie-from-scratch-part-vib.html?m=1

Answer (score 1):

- It cannot be that an area has no pressure. The threshold between the high and low might be arbitrary, but where the high ends, the low must start. Look at an isobar map for a reference
  [image]
- It's implausible that high and low pressure regions accurately maps to the landmasses. Look at a satellite image or again at an isobar map: the cyclonic areas span over landmasses and oceans.
- It's equally implausible that there is a precise, general and worldwide switch between high and low pressure areas going from January to July.